# connecting to ms sql 2017 server using Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, oledb

I have got an old application developed in Vb.net. It uses MS Access database. But now I need to use MS SQL 2017 server in place of access database.

```
Private m_ConnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" 'testdat.mdb"
```

how to change the above connection string to use MS SQL 2017 server with the application.

Comment: When looking for a connection string. [this site](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) is your best friend, ever.
To answer your question directly, we will need to know the server name, database name, and authentication method

Comment: Thanks. I'd checked that site. But under OLEDB section, they didn't provide anything connect with Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0. The application currently uses this provider as shown in the snippet with the question. can I use the same provider to connect to SQL server or whether I need to change this provider?

Comment: You will need to change the provider. To connect to an MS Sql database, you can use the .Net Sql Client, OleDB, or ODBC. Most people would prefer to use the .Net Sql Client over others first.

Comment: Thanks, mate. Could you please provide an example. How to connect SQL server in Vb.net application.

Comment: Take a look at this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, @JayV. I'll check that.

Comment: That needs many code changes. I'm planning to use OleDB. My database servers is now using windows authentication. That needs to be changed?

Comment: Make sure you put `Integrated Security=SSPI;` in to the connection string

Comment: I tried Integrated Security=SSPI.
But getting the error: 
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication

Comment: Private m_ConnStringRecord As String = "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=192.168.2.33\MSSQLEXP2017;Initial Catalog=Record;Integrated Security=SSPI;TrustServerCertificate=True"

This is how my connection string looks like now

Comment: Can you put this a new question, please? More people will be likely to see it and may be able to help with a new question that has new issues rather than an old one.

Comment: Thanks mate for your answers